# Dropbox context menu disappears from TotalFinder after some time

Tags: macos, dropbox

For a few months I've been struggling with strange behaviour two of my apps: TotalFinder and Dropbox. The issue is combined with the Dropbox menu available on right-click. When I start my computer with Dropbox and TotalFinder the menu appears for some time. After I don't know what, it is gone.

I've asked Dropbox Support about that and TotalFinder Support as well. No solution till now.

TotalFinder 1.7.10 and 1.7.12
Dropbox 3.14.7

Below is part of the Console log from the computer startup until I noticed the issue again.

```
24/02/16 13:31:15,316 TotalFinder[350]: agent v1.7.10 started (TotalFinder)
24/02/16 13:31:15,725 Bartender[312]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /Applications/1Password 4.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/2BUA8C4S2C.com.agilebits.onepassword4-helper.app; it may not be scriptable.
24/02/16 13:31:15,731 Bartender[312]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /Applications/DragonDrop.app; it may not be scriptable.
24/02/16 13:31:15,737 Bartender[312]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /System/Library/CoreServices/NotificationCenter.app; it may not be scriptable.
24/02/16 13:31:15,752 Bartender[312]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemUIServer.app; it may not be scriptable.
24/02/16 13:31:15,756 Bartender[312]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /Library/Little Snitch/Little Snitch Agent.app; it may not be scriptable.
24/02/16 13:31:15,765 2BUA8C4S2C.com.agilebits.onepassword4-helper[255]: Bartender Loaded
24/02/16 13:31:15,767 Bartender[312]: Bartender Loaded
24/02/16 13:31:15,772 DragonDrop[317]: Bartender Loaded
24/02/16 13:31:15,784 SystemUIServer[234]: Bartender Loaded
24/02/16 13:31:15,786 NotificationCenter[263]: Bartender Loaded
24/02/16 13:31:15,839 WindowServer[108]: disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "Typinator" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
24/02/16 13:31:16,187 com.apple.time[227]: Interval maximum value is 946100000 seconds (specified value: 9223372036854775807).
24/02/16 13:31:16,211 Bartender[312]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /Applications/CuteClips3.app; it may not be scriptable.
24/02/16 13:31:16,401 com.apple.NotesMigratorService[369]: Joined Aqua audit session
24/02/16 13:31:16,444 Bartender[312]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /Applications/1Password 4.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/2BUA8C4S2C.com.agilebits.onepassword4-helper.app; it may not be scriptable.
24/02/16 13:31:16,448 Bartender[312]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /Applications/DragonDrop.app; it may not be scriptable.
24/02/16 13:31:16,463 com.apple.internetaccounts[301]: An instance 0x7f92dc0843c0 of class IMAPMailbox was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x7f92dc07a450> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7f92dc084440: Observer: 0x7f92dc083b50, Key path: uidNext, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x7fff8b2ee43b, Property: 0x7f92d9ed36d0>
)
24/02/16 13:31:16,493 com.apple.internetaccounts[301]: An instance 0x7f92d9ef0e20 of class IMAPMailbox was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x7f92d9ef1040> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7f92d9ef0ed0: Observer: 0x7f92d9eefd70, Key path: uidNext, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x7fff8b2ee43b, Property: 0x7f92d9ed36d0>
)
24/02/16 13:31:16,518 com.apple.internetaccounts[301]: An instance 0x7f92dc112930 of class IMAPMailbox was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x7f92dc1129e0> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7f92dc135fa0: Observer: 0x7f92dc112ad0, Key path: uidNext, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x7fff8b2ee43b, Property: 0x7f92d9ed36d0>
)
24/02/16 13:31:16,536 com.apple.internetaccounts[301]: An instance 0x7f92dc232830 of class IMAPMailbox was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x7f92dc232950> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7f92dc2328e0: Observer: 0x7f92dc232140, Key path: uidNext, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x7fff8b2ee43b, Property: 0x7f92d9ed36d0>
)
24/02/16 13:31:16,538 Bartender[312]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /System/Library/CoreServices/NotificationCenter.app; it may not be scriptable.
24/02/16 13:31:16,553 com.apple.internetaccounts[301]: An instance 0x7f92dc08ae00 of class IMAPMailbox was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x7f92dc08af20> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7f92dc08aeb0: Observer: 0x7f92dc089d40, Key path: uidNext, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x7fff8b2ee43b, Property: 0x7f92d9ed36d0>
)
24/02/16 13:31:16,568 com.apple.internetaccounts[301]: An instance 0x7f92dc155ff0 of class IMAPMailbox was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x7f92dc156110> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7f92dc1560a0: Observer: 0x7f92dc154f30, Key path: uidNext, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x7fff8b2ee43b, Property: 0x7f92d9ed36d0>
)
24/02/16 13:31:16,571 Bartender[312]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemUIServer.app; it may not be scriptable.
24/02/16 13:31:16,578 Bartender[312]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /Library/Little Snitch/Little Snitch Agent.app; it may not be scriptable.
24/02/16 13:31:16,623 Bartender[312]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemUIServer.app; it may not be scriptable.
24/02/16 13:31:16,686 Bartender[312]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /Applications/CuteClips3.app; it may not be scriptable.
24/02/16 13:31:16,741 Console[373]: setPresentationOptions called with NSApplicationPresentationFullScreen when there is no visible fullscreen window; this call will be ignored.
24/02/16 13:31:16,832 com.apple.internetaccounts[301]: An instance 0x7f92dc08cb50 of class IMAPMailbox was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x7f92dc08cc70> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7f92dc08cc00: Observer: 0x7f92dc08ba90, Key path: uidNext, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x7fff8b2ee43b, Property: 0x7f92d9ed36d0>
)
24/02/16 13:31:16,844 Bartender[312]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /Applications/1Password 4.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/2BUA8C4S2C.com.agilebits.onepassword4-helper.app; it may not be scriptable.
24/02/16 13:31:16,847 Bartender[312]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /Applications/DragonDrop.app; it may not be scriptable.
24/02/16 13:31:16,850 Bartender[312]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /System/Library/CoreServices/NotificationCenter.app; it may not be scriptable.
24/02/16 13:31:16,853 Bartender[312]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /Library/Little Snitch/Little Snitch Agent.app; it may not be scriptable.
24/02/16 13:31:16,855 com.apple.internetaccounts[301]: An instance 0x7f92d9efb7e0 of class IMAPMailbox was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x7f92d9efb890> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7f92d9efb8f0: Observer: 0x7f92d9efb060, Key path: uidNext, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x7fff8b2ee43b, Property: 0x7f92d9ed36d0>
)
24/02/16 13:31:16,889 com.apple.internetaccounts[301]: An instance 0x7f92dc158e00 of class IMAPMailbox was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x7f92dc158f20> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7f92dc158eb0: Observer: 0x7f92dc157d40, Key path: uidNext, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x7fff8b2ee43b, Property: 0x7f92d9ed36d0>
)
24/02/16 13:31:16,890 Bartender[312]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemUIServer.app; it may not be scriptable.
24/02/16 13:31:16,907 com.apple.internetaccounts[301]: An instance 0x7f92dc32e1b0 of class IMAPMailbox was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x7f92dc32e2d0> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7f92dc32e260: Observer: 0x7f92dc32d0e0, Key path: uidNext, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x7fff8b2ee43b, Property: 0x7f92d9ed36d0>
)
24/02/16 13:31:16,923 com.apple.internetaccounts[301]: An instance 0x7f92dc15d560 of class IMAPMailbox was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x7f92dc15d680> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7f92dc15d610: Observer: 0x7f92dc15c4a0, Key path: uidNext, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x7fff8b2ee43b, Property: 0x7f92d9ed36d0>
)
24/02/16 13:31:16,938 com.apple.internetaccounts[301]: An instance 0x7f92dc08ea00 of class IMAPMailbox was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x7f92dc08eb20> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7f92dc08eab0: Observer: 0x7f92dc08d940, Key path: uidNext, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x7fff8b2ee43b, Property: 0x7f92d9ed36d0>
)
24/02/16 13:31:17,081 Bartender[312]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /Applications/CuteClips3.app; it may not be scriptable.
24/02/16 13:31:17,084 Bartender[312]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /Library/Little Snitch/Little Snitch Agent.app; it may not be scriptable.
24/02/16 13:31:17,205 com.apple.internetaccounts[301]: An instance 0x7f92dc32dcb0 of class IMAPMailbox was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x7f92dc32cc70> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7f92dc32dd30: Observer: 0x7f92dc32db70, Key path: uidNext, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x7fff8b2ee43b, Property: 0x7f92d9ed36d0>
)
24/02/16 13:31:17,230 com.apple.internetaccounts[301]: An instance 0x7f92dc0b3580 of class IMAPMailbox was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x7f92dc0b3700> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7f92dc0b3690: Observer: 0x7f92dc0b24c0, Key path: uidNext, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x7fff8b2ee43b, Property: 0x7f92d9ed36d0>
)
24/02/16 13:31:17,321 TotalFinder[350]: requesting injection into com.apple.finder[235]
24/02/16 13:31:17,348 Bartender[312]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /Applications/CuteClips3.app; it may not be scriptable.
24/02/16 13:31:17,708 System Events[372]: .sdef warning for part of complex type 'any | number | boolean | date | list | record | text | data' used in suite 'Property List Suite': 'data' is not a valid type name.
24/02/16 13:31:17,710 System Events[372]: .sdef warning for type 'text | missing value | any' attribute 'uniqueID' of class 'XML element' in suite 'XML Suite': AppleScript ID references may not work for this property because its type is not NSNumber- or NSString-derived.
24/02/16 13:31:18,309 usernoted[250]: Failed to validate application at (null) -67071
24/02/16 13:31:18,541 WindowServer[108]: common_reenable_update: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "Typinator" after 3.70 seconds (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.00 seconds)
24/02/16 13:31:18,545 CuteClips3[337]: Bartender Loaded
24/02/16 13:31:18,596 WindowServer[108]: disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "Default Folder X Helper" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
24/02/16 13:31:18,000 kernel[0]: CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1000): p=399[CleanMyMacHelper] final status 0x0, allowing (remove VALID) page
24/02/16 13:31:18,810 Typinator[316]: Bartender Loaded
24/02/16 13:31:19,125 WindowServer[108]: disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "Console" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
24/02/16 13:31:19,274 CleanMyMacHelperTool[399]: Mounted devices (
)
24/02/16 13:31:19,283 CleanMyMacHelperTool[399]: CleanMyMacHelperTool started as volume cleaner with cleanTrashes 1 cleanMacOSJunk 1 cleanWinJunk 1
24/02/16 13:31:19,284 CleanMyMacHelperTool[399]: Mounted devices (
)
24/02/16 13:31:19,285 CleanMyMacHelperTool[399]: Wont clean mounted devices.
24/02/16 13:31:19,286 CleanMyMacHelperTool[399]: CleanMyMacHelperTool exited...
24/02/16 13:31:19,312 Finder[235]: TotalFinderInjector v1.7.12 received init event
24/02/16 13:31:19,313 Finder[235]: TotalFinderInjector: Installing TotalFinder from /Library/ScriptingAdditions/TotalFinder.osax/Contents/Resources/TotalFinder.bundle
24/02/16 13:31:19,501 Daylite Sync Helper[257]: Finished starting PG at: 2016-02-24 12:31:19 +0000
24/02/16 13:31:19,501 Daylite Sync Helper[257]: Server did start - looking for orphaned temp tables
24/02/16 13:31:19,515 Finder[235]: Launching TotalFinderCrashWatcher from '/Library/ScriptingAdditions/TotalFinder.osax/Contents/Resources/TotalFinder.bundle/Contents/Resources/TotalFinderCrashWatcher.app'
24/02/16 13:31:19,540 Finder[235]: Not installing Apple Event handler for GURL - because of TotalFinderNoAEHandlers tweak is on
24/02/16 13:31:19,562 TotalFinderCrashWatcher[402]: Watching '/Users/lukasz/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports' for new crash reports with prefix 'Finder'
24/02/16 13:31:19,633 Daylite Sync Helper[257]: <DLPGServer : 0x7fc718407250> (didStartServer): Checking BUILDgreenDesign_test_OFFLINE for orphaned temp tables
24/02/16 13:31:19,669 Daylite Sync Helper[257]: <DLPGServer : 0x7fc718407250> (didStartServer):   11124 - pg_temp_1
24/02/16 13:31:19,691 Daylite Sync Helper[257]: <DLPGServer : 0x7fc718407250> (didStartServer):   23893 - pg_temp_2
24/02/16 13:31:19,693 Daylite Sync Helper[257]: <DLPGServer : 0x7fc718407250> (didStartServer):   24214 - pg_temp_3
24/02/16 13:31:19,695 Daylite Sync Helper[257]: <DLPGServer : 0x7fc718407250> (didStartServer):   24232 - pg_temp_4
24/02/16 13:31:19,697 Daylite Sync Helper[257]: <DLPGServer : 0x7fc718407250> (didStartServer):   24242 - pg_temp_5
24/02/16 13:31:19,699 Daylite Sync Helper[257]: <DLPGServer : 0x7fc718407250> (didStartServer):   24263 - pg_temp_6
24/02/16 13:31:19,701 Daylite Sync Helper[257]: <DLPGServer : 0x7fc718407250> (didStartServer):   24308 - pg_temp_7
24/02/16 13:31:19,703 Daylite Sync Helper[257]: <DLPGServer : 0x7fc718407250> (didStartServer):   25167 - pg_temp_8
24/02/16 13:31:19,756 Daylite Sync Helper[257]: <DLPGServer : 0x7fc718407250> (didStartServer):   36644 - pg_temp_9
24/02/16 13:31:19,764 Daylite Sync Helper[257]: <DLPGServer : 0x7fc718407250> (didStartServer):   36654 - pg_temp_10
24/02/16 13:31:19,767 Daylite Sync Helper[257]: <DLPGServer : 0x7fc718407250> (didStartServer):   36672 - pg_temp_11
24/02/16 13:31:19,769 Daylite Sync Helper[257]: <DLPGServer : 0x7fc718407250> (didStartServer):   36704 - pg_temp_12
24/02/16 13:31:19,771 Daylite Sync Helper[257]: <DLPGServer : 0x7fc718407250> (didStartServer):   36855 - pg_temp_13
24/02/16 13:31:19,773 Daylite Sync Helper[257]: <DLPGServer : 0x7fc718407250> (didStartServer):   36905 - pg_temp_14
24/02/16 13:31:19,806 Daylite Sync Helper[257]: Going to unlock the environment.
24/02/16 13:31:19,807 Daylite Sync Helper[257]:   successfully unlocked the environment.
24/02/16 13:31:19,898 Finder[235]: Invalid color System, labelColor (warning given only once)
24/02/16 13:31:20,003 WindowServer[108]: disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "System Preferences" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
24/02/16 13:31:20,260 Finder[235]: Not installing Apple Event handlers - because of TotalFinderNoAEHandlers tweak is on
24/02/16 13:31:20,271 System Preferences[347]: Failed to find MagicPrefs.app
24/02/16 13:31:20,384 System Preferences[347]: Not restoring trackpad tracking speed to 0.000000
24/02/16 13:31:20,886 TotalFinder[350]: TotalFinder has been succesfully injected into com.apple.finder[235]
24/02/16 13:31:20,982 Finder[235]: TotalFinderInjector v1.7.12 received init event
24/02/16 13:31:20,982 Finder[235]: TotalFinderInjector: TotalFinder has been already loaded. Ignoring this request.
24/02/16 13:31:20,985 TotalFinder[350]: TotalFinder has been succesfully injected into com.apple.finder[235]
24/02/16 13:31:21,334 WindowServer[108]: common_reenable_update: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "Default Folder X Helper" after 3.74 seconds (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.00 seconds)
24/02/16 13:31:22,166 System Preferences[347]: Not restoring trackpad tracking speed to 0.000000
24/02/16 13:31:22,370 Karabiner[343]: checkForUpdates https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/files/appcast.xml
24/02/16 13:31:23,322 WindowServer[108]: common_reenable_update: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "System Preferences" after 4.32 seconds (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.00 seconds)
24/02/16 13:31:23,640 Bartender[312]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /Applications/Cinch.app; it may not be scriptable.
24/02/16 13:31:23,691 Bartender[312]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /Applications/Cinch.app; it may not be scriptable.
24/02/16 13:31:23,714 WindowServer[108]: common_reenable_update: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "Console" after 5.59 seconds (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.00 seconds)
24/02/16 13:31:23,855 Cinch[339]: Bartender Loaded
24/02/16 13:31:23,863 Karabiner[343]: [INFO] BRIDGE_USERCLIENT_SYNCHRONIZED_COMMUNICATION connection is null
24/02/16 13:31:23,863 Karabiner[343]: [INFO] BRIDGE_USERCLIENT_SYNCHRONIZED_COMMUNICATION connection is null
24/02/16 13:31:23,864 Karabiner[343]: [INFO] BRIDGE_USERCLIENT_SYNCHRONIZED_COMMUNICATION connection is null
24/02/16 13:31:23,900 Karabiner[343]: [INFO] BRIDGE_USERCLIENT_SYNCHRONIZED_COMMUNICATION connection is null
24/02/16 13:31:23,900 Karabiner[343]: [INFO] BRIDGE_USERCLIENT_SYNCHRONIZED_COMMUNICATION connection is null
24/02/16 13:31:23,916 Karabiner[343]: Session state has been changed. (active)
24/02/16 13:31:24,229 Karabiner[343]: [INFO] BRIDGE_USERCLIENT_SYNCHRONIZED_COMMUNICATION connection is null
24/02/16 13:31:24,281 cocoAspell[423]: Attempting to regirster 22 dictionaries
24/02/16 13:31:24,286 cocoAspell[423]: cocoAspell registered English (United Kingdom) [ise-w_accents] from /Library/Application Support/cocoAspell/aspell6-en-6.0-0/en_GB-ise-w_accents
24/02/16 13:31:24,290 cocoAspell[423]: cocoAspell registered Polish from /Library/Application Support/cocoAspell/aspell6-pl-6.0_20150428-0/pl
24/02/16 13:31:24,292 cocoAspell[423]: Starting Aspell SpellChecker.
24/02/16 13:31:24,344 Karabiner[343]: observer_IONotification
24/02/16 13:31:24,345 Karabiner[343]: [INFO] BRIDGE_USERCLIENT_SYNCHRONIZED_COMMUNICATION connection is null
24/02/16 13:31:24,000 kernel[0]: org.pqrs.Karabiner --Info-- RemapClass::allocation_count_ 417857/2097152 (memory usage: 19% of 8192KB)
24/02/16 13:31:24,901 Default Folder X Helper[345]: Bartender Loaded
24/02/16 13:31:25,048 WindowServer[108]: disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "Finder" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
24/02/16 13:31:25,479 Karabiner_AXNotifier[424]: AXNotifier Preferences: {
    kAXNotifierDisabledInJavaApps = 1;
    kAXNotifierDisabledInPreview = 1;
}
24/02/16 13:31:26,238 parentalcontrolsd[430]: StartObservingFSEvents [849:] -- *** StartObservingFSEvents started event stream
24/02/16 13:31:27,097 Typinator[316]: *** event error: -1712
24/02/16 13:31:30,028 Dropbox[349]: PyObjCPointer created: at 0x110eff8d8 of type ^{OpaqueJSContext=}
24/02/16 13:31:31,584 Bartender[312]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /Applications/Dropbox.app; it may not be scriptable.
24/02/16 13:31:31,615 Dropbox[349]: Bartender Loaded
24/02/16 13:31:32,000 kernel[0]: fsevents: watcher dbfseventsd (pid: 509) - Using /dev/fsevents directly is unsupported.  Migrate to FSEventsFramework
24/02/16 13:31:32,405 storeagent[427]: multibyte ASN1 identifiers are  not supported.
24/02/16 13:31:32,590 storeagent[427]: multibyte ASN1 identifiers are  not supported.
24/02/16 13:31:33,049 appleeventsd[85]: , error #268435460 (ipc/send) timed out attepting to send eEntitlement for pid 235, port ( port:16131/0x3f03 rcv:0,send:3,d:0) from senderPid 521 (sendEntitlementsToMachPort()/appleEventsD.cp #1916) client-reqs-q
24/02/16 13:31:33,231 appleeventsd[85]: , error #268435460 (ipc/send) timed out attepting to send eEntitlement for pid 235, port ( port:16131/0x3f03 rcv:0,send:4,d:0) from senderPid 528 (sendEntitlementsToMachPort()/appleEventsD.cp #1916) client-reqs-q
24/02/16 13:31:34,973 System Preferences[347]: .sdef warning for argument 'FileType' of command 'save' in suite 'Standard Suite': 'saveable file format' is not a valid type name.
24/02/16 13:31:36,779 WindowServer[108]: common_reenable_update: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "Finder" after 12.73 seconds (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.00 seconds)
24/02/16 13:31:39,970 WindowServer[108]: disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "Finder" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
24/02/16 13:31:41,675 sandboxd[138]: ([562]) QuickLookSatelli(562) deny file-read-data /Users/lukasz/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.revocation.plist
24/02/16 13:31:41,682 sandboxd[138]: ([562]) QuickLookSatelli(562) deny file-read-data /Users/lukasz/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.revocation.plist
24/02/16 13:31:43,586 appleeventsd[85]: , error #268435460 (ipc/send) timed out attepting to send eEntitlement for pid 235, port ( port:16131/0x3f03 rcv:0,send:5,d:0) from senderPid 565 (sendEntitlementsToMachPort()/appleEventsD.cp #1916) client-reqs-q
24/02/16 13:31:44,791 com.apple.IconServicesAgent[305]: main Failed to composit image for binding VariantBinding [0x279] flags: 0x8 binding: FileInfoBinding [0x381] - extension: png, UTI: public.png, fileType: PiNG.
24/02/16 13:31:44,792 quicklookd[311]: Warning: Cache image returned by the server has size range covering all valid image sizes. Binding: VariantBinding [0x1a03] flags: 0x8 binding: FileInfoBinding [0x1903] - extension: png, UTI: public.png, fileType: PiNG request size:16 scale: 1
24/02/16 13:31:44,799 com.apple.IconServicesAgent[305]: main Failed to composit image for binding VariantBinding [0x6cb] flags: 0x8 binding: FileInfoBinding [0x5e9] - extension: ai, UTI: com.adobe.illustrator.ai-image, fileType: PDF .
24/02/16 13:31:44,800 quicklookd[311]: Warning: Cache image returned by the server has size range covering all valid image sizes. Binding: VariantBinding [0x1c03] flags: 0x8 binding: FileInfoBinding [0x1b03] - extension: ai, UTI: com.adobe.illustrator.ai-image, fileType: PDF  request size:16 scale: 1
24/02/16 13:31:44,804 com.apple.IconServicesAgent[305]: main Failed to composit image for binding VariantBinding [0x27b] flags: 0x8 binding: FileInfoBinding [0x4f3] - extension: mp4, UTI: public.mpeg-4, fileType: ????.
24/02/16 13:31:44,805 quicklookd[311]: Warning: Cache image returned by the server has size range covering all valid image sizes. Binding: VariantBinding [0x1e03] flags: 0x8 binding: FileInfoBinding [0x1d03] - extension: mp4, UTI: public.mpeg-4, fileType: ???? request size:16 scale: 1
24/02/16 13:31:44,814 com.apple.IconServicesAgent[305]: main Failed to composit image for binding VariantBinding [0x5eb] flags: 0x8 binding: FileInfoBinding [0x6cd] - extension: pages, UTI: com.apple.iwork.pages.pages, fileType: ????.
24/02/16 13:31:44,815 quicklookd[311]: Warning: Cache image returned by the server has size range covering all valid image sizes. Binding: VariantBinding [0x2003] flags: 0x8 binding: FileInfoBinding [0x1f03] - extension: pages, UTI: com.apple.iwork.pages.pages, fileType: ???? request size:16 scale: 1
24/02/16 13:31:44,916 WindowServer[108]: common_reenable_update: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "Finder" after 5.95 seconds (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.00 seconds)
24/02/16 13:31:46,251 Dropbox[349]: The function `CGContextClear' is obsolete and will be removed in an upcoming update. Unfortunately, this application, or a library it uses, is using this obsolete function, and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system performance.
24/02/16 13:32:02,648 Dropbox[349]: ICARegisterForEventNotification-Has been deprecated since 10.5.  Calls to this function in the future may crash this application.  Please move to ImageCaptureCore
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem with XtraFinder (a similar but free Finder replacement). My only work around so far has been to "logout" under the Apple menu, then login and there is the Dropbox choices in the right (or control) click contextual menu again.

Logout & login is faster than restarting, tho still inconvenient.

I hope you find a better solution and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I get XtraFinder and for now it happened 3 times. Quit Dropbox and restart Finder is enough for now. Still I haven't idea about the reason of this issue.